# android google map get latitude and longtitude issue

Tags: android, google-maps

I created sample application I want to get latitude and longtitude from string address line. this is my method which I used to get latitude and longtitude

```
private void getFromLocation(String address) {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

            latitude = p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            longtitude = p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
            HAMBURG = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
            Log.d("latitide", "" + latitude);
            Log.d("longtitude", "" + longtitude);

        } else {
            Log.d("Addess", "Address not found");
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("ex", ee.toString());
    }
}
```

This method throws an exception " `java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server`
". Is there any mistake I made? is there any other solution to get latitude and longtitude ?

Answer (score 0):

An IOException is likely to indicate that the remote request failed for some relatively low-level reason;

**`IOException: if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs`**

---

```
public List<Address> getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults)
```

Added in API level 1
Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the named location, which may be a place name such as "Dalvik, Iceland", an address such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", an airport code such as "SFO", etc.. The returned addresses will be localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.

The query will block and returned values will be obtained by means of a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

### Parameters

**locationName:**   a user-supplied description of a location

**maxResults:** max number of results to return. Smaller numbers (1 to 5) are recommended

### **Returns:**

a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

### Throws

**IllegalArgumentException:**   if locationName is null

**IOException:**    if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs

---

So, Do

**Please try to avoid several hits for address in a minute.
Run this code on different device.**

for more detail check this [artical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just read your suggestion from other blogs also. some of other solution I also uninstall apps from my device. and my request from device is not within a minute. is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
     List<Address> foundGeocode = null;
   /* find the addresses  by using getFromLocationName() method with the given address*/
   try {
    foundGeocode = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this).getFromLocationName("Your location",1);
     Double s=foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude(); //getting latitude
       Double n=foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude();
        } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: yes all permission are there even with the latitude and longtitude My map work properly.

Comment: i just want map with string address means without latitude and logntitude